# Rational but not iso. to $\mathbb{P}^1$ $\Rightarrow$ iso. to open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $Y$ be a non-singular curve which is birational to but not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. How can one see that this curve is isomorphic to an open subset of the affine line? This is Hartshorne problem I.6.1.

Thoughts so far: By the definition of birational equivalence, there is an isomorphism $\varphi: U \to V$ of open subsets of $Y$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$, respectively. Since $Y$ has the cofinite topology, it should be possible to use Hartshorne's Proposition I.6.8 to extend $\varphi$ to $Y$. However, I can't see why the map so defined should be an isomorphism.

Comment: If $Y$ is projective, it can not be isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$. Also, $Y$ obviously has to be non singular. Are you sure of the hypotheses ?

Comment: Hi Roland. You're right, I should have said it needs to be non-singular.

Comment: Do you know that any non singular curve is an open subset of a projective one ?

Comment: I've seen this statement, yes.

Comment: Ok, so you are almost done right ? What could be this projective closure ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: So $Y$ is an open subset of a projective curve $\overline{Y}$. Now $\overline{Y}$ is birationnal to $\mathbb{P}^1$. So in fact, $\overline{Y}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Hence $Y$ is isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^1$. And because it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, it is isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: Nice. I think I had an issue with terminology, but your response has cleared it up. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.